# How to get json encoded values using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

This is my html where i want to get below json values:

```
<div id='bodyText'></div>
```

Here i have json encoded PHP value for

```
$page->results()
```

as follows in below jquery items:

```
[{name:'abc',id:'10'},
{name:'def',id:'20'}]
```

And below using jquery code how would i get these above values within div elements with id 'bodyText'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var items = <?php echo json_encode($page->results()); ?>;
            $.each(items, function(key, val) {
                $('bodyText').append($.text(val));
            });

        });
```

I am unable to get the values please help me to solve the problem...

Comment: I think you couldn't use php script in javascript section

Comment: Actually, you can access server-side variables (`PHP`) from the client-side (`Javascript`) if they are available. You can't do the inverse, in this later case you have to make POST messages to the server to send information.

Comment: can you please guide me with some examples please...

Answer (score 0):

you are not correct referencing `bodyText` div id. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var items = <?php echo json_encode($page->results()); ?>;
    $.each(items, function(key, val) {
        $('#bodyText').append($.text(val));
    });

});
```

you need to change this `$('bodyText').append($.text(val));` to `$('#bodyText').append($.text(val));`